# Airplane ticket booked under my middle name

Tags: air-travel, tickets, tsa

I use my middle name pretty much everywhere.  At work I used to book travel myself and would always book under my first and last name.  We recently hired an admin who booked travel using my middle and last name.

Jet blue refused to change the ticket (or perhaps wasn't able to?).  The only option was to cancel the flight and re-book it at the last minute price, of course.  The other option is to show up to the flight and risk TSA refusing to let me travel.

Any advice?

Comment: Is your middle name shown on your passport / other government ID you'd use to travel with?

Comment: My middle name is on my passport.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Airlines don't usually match your full name. First-last, last-first is almost 100% ok with every airline.

Comment: You will probably need to show your credit card (the one that was used to book the flight).

Comment: right, but my *real* first name is no where on the ticket.  The ticket was purchased using a corporate card.

Comment: I'm glad you got help. I always ask anyone that I'm booking travel for to send me the exact information they want used. Some people have TSA Redress numbers and/or Known Traveler ID numbers, too.

Answer (score 11):

Turns out that when I tweeted Jet Blue they were willing to work with me and change the name on the ticket to First Middle Last.  This should solve my problem since First Middle Last is on my passport.

I find it a bit odd these days that you have more luck getting help from Twitter instead of using the normal channels of your travel agent OR calling the airline directly.

Comment: Perhaps the difference is in whether they're asked to change to Middle Last to First Middle, or to First Middle Last? In the former case it will be hard for them to see the ticket isn't being transferred to someone else (which they don't want to allow for business reasons), whereas _adding_ a name just makes the ticket _more_ specific.

Comment: It's called being afraid of negative publicity. :)

Comment: A+ for the solution. Can you share the tweet? or did you DM?