# Spelling mistake on my Air ticket

Tags: visas, air-travel

By mistake I misspelled my last name while booking air ticket, It was supposed to be GanGArajuvardhana instead of GanAGrajuvardhana (I've highlighted the mistake in uppercase letters). Will that be a problem at immigration?

Comment: If you purchase ticket directly from airline website/office, you can change it at the time of checkin

Comment: But it may cost some money

Comment: Which immigration are you talking about? The one at the departure country or the one at the destination country? Note that for some destination countries, the name on the passport and on the ticket *have* to be the same (USA comes into mind here - at least for non-US citizens). So in such cases, you will *need* to get your ticket altered. Depending on the airline, this may be done free of charge at check-in time, but not all airlines do that. In any case, you may want to add information about your countries of travel and airline.

Comment: Related: *[My name is not the same on ticket as on passport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22088/)*, *[Am I going to have trouble flying with a reversed name on the ticket?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16644)*, *[Name on ticket abbreviated in passport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38744)*, *[Middle name missing on flight reservation, API needs middle name](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36522)*, *[Name mismatch on airline ticket/insurance](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/23615)*, *[Airplane ticket booked under my middle name](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38488)*.